# how to cast to datetime and get month as name

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I'm wondering how to cast to datetime, but get the name of the month instead of the month as an integer. I'm doing the casting within a listview control. Thanks!

```
<asp:ListView  ID="listviewAttachments" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="announcementPost">
                <td class="posted">
                   <h6> <span> <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).Month%>  </span></h6>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h6> <span> <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).ToString("MMMM")%>  </span></h6>
```

Comment: @jre247 Glad it worked... if this answer, or other answers to your questions have been helpful, please "accept" the answer to give credit to whoever helped:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).ToString("MMM")%> --for short/abbrievated month name
```

OR

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).ToString("MMMM")%> --for full month name
```

Reference:
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Alternatively, if you need culture specific month names, then you could try these:
[DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname.aspx)
[DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).ToString("MMMM");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function 
`MonthName(Month(Date.Now))` in asp.net code behind.